# Playing Audio with pipeline in Gstreamer (C#)

Tags: c#, audio, media, gstreamer, pipeline

I've been struggling with GStreamer for a while because I can't find any C# examples/tutorials.

As far as I know, Gstreamer uses pipelines in order to decode and then be able to send, for instance a song, to the speakers, but I tried the following, which didn't work:

```
        Gst.Element pipeline;
        string path = @"some_path.mp3";
        string command = "filesrc location=" + path + " ! oggdemux ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! gconfaudiosink";
        pipeline = Gst.Parse.Launch(command);
        pipeline.SetState(Gst.State.Playing);
```

However, it raises an exception in the Gst.Parse.Launch line

Does anyone know any good application example, and/or can actually post some code, so I can start getting used to the library? Also, if you can tell me what's wrong on the code above, I'd be thankful

Without further ado,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just change your command string to "filesrc location=" + path + " ! decodebin2 ! gconfaudiosink", that should work.

On a side note you should use the gst-launch tool on the command line to check if your pipeline is working and to debug it. Also use gst-inspect to find which plugins are available on your system and what is their functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still raises the same exception :/ About that tool, when I try to launch it, it says that it couldn't be loaded because I don't have pythhon26.dll on my computer. I installed gstreamer msi and sdk, am I missing something?

Comment: Where did you download the msi and sdk from?

Comment: Also, try replacing gconfaudiosink with autoaudiosink and see if it works.

Comment: Here's the link: https://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/downloads/list
I downloaded the 2nd and the 4th link(v10.7 GPL)
autoaudiosink didn't work as well
Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your installation. This link addresses a similar problem :http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2011-July/032164.html. I'd suggest reinstalling with v10.6 sdk(not the beta version you downloaded).